# How to move code fragment to a diffrent file in c++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11

I'm writing in `C++` and my code is getting bigger and bigger. I wonder if I could somehow move code fragment to a different file. Let's say i have:

```
class First {
    class Second
    {
        void a();
        void b();
    };
    void c();
};
```

I would like to move my Second class to a Second.h file and then of course write bodies of Second class and functions into Second.cpp file. How can I do this?

Comment: ....try copy and paste? Sorry, it's not at all clear what you're asking, what you've tried, what problems you're having, etc.

Comment: Why do you want/need that kind of separation? Can you elaborate about your actual use case please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `class Second` is nested in `class First` you could start by refactoring your code like so:

```
class First
{
    class Second;
    void c();
};
class First::Second
{
    void a();
    void b();
};
```

From there it is easy to break the two classes into separate files:

First.h:

```
class First
{
    class Second;
    void c();
};
```

And Second.h

```
#include "First.h"

class First::Second
{
    void a();
    void b();
};
```

And then your `.cpp` files would be:

First.cpp

```
#include "First.h"
void First::c()
{

}
```

Second.cpp

```
#include "Second.h"
void First::Second::a()
{

}

void First::Second::b()
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that's what i meant. I followed your way. Now tho i wanted to make object of my Second class (in First class), however my compiler throws error: "Incomplete type is not allowed" and "First::a uses undefined class First::Second", despite my Second class HAS body, like in your code. Do you know maybe why can't I create the object?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no good way of doing this. That is one of the downsides of having nested classes, especially when they are broken up like that. If i had to suggest I would just keep `First` and `Second` in the same header. It would be just like the first code snippet in my example. You can have the implementations in separate `.cpp` files still. The issue is that `First` Does not have a complete declaration of `Second` in its header, only  forward declaration.

Comment: @Adas Why are you using nested classes in the first place? Are you sure you don't just want an *instance* of `Second` as a *member* of `First`? Also, if you break up the code this way, then users of `First` will need to include `Second.h`. To avoid this, put `#include Second.h` at the *bottom* of `First.h`, and make sure you add [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have `First.h`

```
class First{
    class Second
    {
        void a();
        void b();
    };
    void c();
};
```

you can provide the implementation of `class Second` in a separate translation unit:
like

First.cpp:

```
#include "First.h"
void First::c() {
}
```

Second.cpp:

```
#include "First.h"

void First::Second::a() {
}
void First::Second::b() {
}
```

I'm not sure that's what you're after though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's pretty much what i wanted